# I'm working with a table where the last column is of the 16368 place numerarii, and in this case, the code fails

Tags: c#, excel

I have already created a similar topic, I found how to find the last column.
The subsequent code only works with a small number of dates. I'm working with a table where the last column is of the 16368 place numerarii, and somehow, in this case, the code fails.

```
//number of the last column
int x = MatrixRange.Collumns.Count; 

//here I check to see what is the numbering column 
//(oddly enough, I get always the correct number, but the column the program does not issue
textBox1.Text = x.ToString();

for (int Rnum = 6; Rnum <= MatrixRange.Cells.Count; Rnum++)
{
     if ((MatrixRange.Cells[Rnum,x] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
     {
          //at this point the program will either ignore this function or shows an error, 
          //if x = 10, not 16368, then the code works great
          string TabZeile = (MatrixRange.Cells[Rnum,x] as Eexcel.Range).Value2.ToString(); 

          neuXml.Cells [Rnum,4] = TabZeile;    
     }    
}
```

Comment: in the line where you assign to TabZeile you have `Eexcel`, should this be `Excel`?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What is "numerarii"?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Excel has [limitations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

One of them (you should check others in link above):

> Worksheet size 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns